# textBox losing values on postback?

Tags: c#, asp.net, page-lifecycle

I have asp.net page (Form = runat server  )

2 textboxes:

```
<input type="text" id="tb1" />
<asp:TextBox ID="tb2" runat="server" />
```

and a button submit.

However when I put some values in them - and press the button - Only tb2 is getting back its value from the server.

I thought that inputs fields values are going from client to  server and back always !

in what event ( in page life cycle) Does tb1 lose its value ?

Comment: How (where) do you look for the Value of tb1 ?

Comment: @HenkHolterman I want to see it back on the screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The POST will contain information entered in tb1 - so it can be read from the Request

if you change it to

```
<input type="text" id="tb1"  runat="server" />
```

it will work as you want.

without the runat=server it does not "lose" its value - it will never be populated - ever, because it is simply data in the POST and not connected to a server side control.

one final point - to explicitly answer some of your comments - the POST data is processed just before the PreLoad event - this can be found from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

Comment: i know i can read it by request.form but in what phase asp.net life cycle - it puts back the value to tb2 ( and not tb1) ?

Comment: @royi - stop comparing tb1 and tb2. They are totally different.

Comment: the other posts are correct - it will not be re-entered as this is not a server side control (unless of course you enter runat=server)

Answer (score 4):

`<input type="text" id="tb1" />` is literal HTML.
There is no server-side code that puts the value back in.

That feature is part of server-side controls.

Comment: in what event ( in page life cycle) Does tb1 lose its value ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir That question makes no sense. `tb1` is NOT a server side control, it is not involved in the server side page lifecycle at all.

Comment: The value of tb1 never gets set to a control on the server side, so it  never loses its value.  You can access the value via the `Request` property if you prefer.

Comment: @RoyiNamir That's the problem, it doesn't even go through this cycle, at least the only stage where this HTML code and the server code interact is when the HTML is rendered. So if you really want to touch this HTML you need to override the Render method.

Comment: @RoyiNamir: `tb1` **doesn't exist**.  It's just literal HTML; there is no value or object.

Answer (score 1):

`tb1` is not a server side control, it is a normal html dom object.

You should find its value after a post in the `Request.Form` value collection however.

Comment: i know i can read it by request.form but in what phase asp.net life cycle - it puts back the value to tb2 ( and not tb1)

Comment: @RoyiNamir See my other response.